# What does r.js really do?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, r.js

I'm trying to understand the benefits of the popular [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/).

It seems to...

- concatenate a list of *manually selected* JavaScript files
- uglify/minimize that combined code
- do some similar stuff for CSS files (combine them)

Also, (*what it makes it different from generic combine/minify tools*) it seems to...

- convert Node-style `require()` modules to AMD style modules
- name anonymous modules (eg. `define(['dependency'], function(){...}`)
- offer some support for loader plugins, e.g. inline CSS files

It does **not** seem to...

- analyze and automatically resolve dependencies found in files (like, include file `foo.js` into the package just because r.js finds a `define(["foo"], ...)`

Is this correct, or did I miss something?

Comment: Uh, was my edit incorrect and you really meant that it should "*include file `foo.js` into the package just because r.js finds a **`define(["foo"], ...)`***"? If the code is already there (`foo` is defined), I don't see why you would want it to load the `foo.js` file.

Comment: [RequireJS/Optimization](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html): "[r.js] Combines related scripts together into build layers and minifies them". The dependency graph itself is *still resolved at run-time*, all the modules have simply been shoved together and so do not require separate resource fetches.

Comment: @Bergi: Don't know about your edit, but yes, I want to make sure that it's correct that r.js does not automatically resolve any dependencies. I'm not saying it *should* do so. It just appears to me that r.js does some heavy JavaScript parsing/processing and want to make sure I understand all steps in that process.

Comment: @user2864740: so, for modules that are already AMD-style, r.js does not do any special processing that can't be done by a classic combiner/minifier? (no criticism intended)

Comment: @UdoG I mean: Normal module-per-file dependencies will be included, pretty much unless excluded, but the object graphs/load-order won't be.

Comment: @UdoG how would u handle any non amd dependencies though without r.js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are wrong, because `r.js` does automatically resolve dependencies. If you have a `main.js` file with this:

```
define(["foo"], function (foo) {
});
```

Then if you ask `r.js` to create produce an optimized module out of `main.js`, it **will** include the code for module `foo` into the build.

Some caveats:

1. It is possible to tell `r.js` to exclude modules. So if a module you think should be in an optimized bundle is absent, it may be that it has been excluded. (You know how you are using `r.js` but if you use a bundle produced by *someone else* and you wonder, then this may be the answer: they specifically excluded a dependency from the build.)
2. `r.js` does not find *nested* dependencies unless you tell it to. For instance:

   ```
   define(function () {
       require(["foo"], function (foo) {
       });
   });
   ```

   `r.js` won't find that `foo` is required unless you set `findNestedDepencencies` to `true` in your build config.
3. `r.js` can find only dependencies that are specified in the form of a list of string placed as a literal in the location where the `require` and `define` calls expect dependencies. So if you do:

   ```
   define(function () {
       var deps = ["foo"];
       require(deps, function (foo) {
       });
   });
   ```

   Then `r.js` won't know that `foo` is a dependency, because in `require(deps, ...` your dependencies appear as a symbol reference, not as a list of strings. You would have to specify `foo` as a dependency manually in the build configuration. There's no flag to turn on to make `r.js` find these cases.